# Optaplanner - Null Pointer Exception from AbstractTabuAcceptor class in default environment mode

Tags: optaplanner

I thought this question has been fixed by v7 as this JIRA story: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-757, but when I use nullable = True in planning variable with Tabu search, it still throws null pointer error in the 'adjustTabuList' method. Has anyone else encountered the same issue?

Comment: Which version are you using? Can you paste your stacktrace here?

Comment: I am using the latest 7.14 Final version, built by using Maven pom.xml file. The full stacktrace is as elow:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.util.ArrayDeque.addLast(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ArrayDeque.add(Unknown Source)
 at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.decider.acceptor.tabu.AbstractTabuAcceptor.adjustTabuList(AbstractTabuAcceptor.java:133)
 at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.decider.acceptor.tabu.AbstractTabuAcceptor.stepEnded(AbstractTabuAcceptor.java:104)

Comment: at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.decider.acceptor.CompositeAcceptor.stepEnded(CompositeAcceptor.java:83)
 at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.decider.LocalSearchDecider.stepEnded(LocalSearchDecider.java:162)
 at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.DefaultLocalSearchPhase.stepEnded(DefaultLocalSearchPhase.java:130)
 at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.DefaultLocalSearchPhase.solve(DefaultLocalSearchPhase.java:93)
 at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolver.runPhases(AbstractSolver.java:88)
 at ...

Comment: The error only comes up in the middle of the tabu search. I have the following configuration for this local search:
<acceptor>
   <solutionTabuSize>100</solutionTabuSize>
   <moveTabuSize>7</moveTabuSize>
   <entityTabuRatio>0.03</entityTabuRatio>
   <valueTabuSize>7</valueTabuSize>
  </acceptor>
  <forager>
   <acceptedCountLimit>500</acceptedCountLimit>
   <pickEarlyType>FIRST_BEST_SCORE_IMPROVING</pickEarlyType>
  </forager>

Comment: More specifically, I tried commented out each of the tabu settings and found the error comes from 'valueTabuSize' setting (of course because it's a planning value that is null)

Comment: What's the motivation to use mutliple tabu acceptors? Ussually only entityTabu is good (without risk of overfitting)